# why web.py template could not display <br>?

Tags: python, html, web.py

I got json data from my server api and displayed to the web page.While it was always display as follows:
[image]

The reading data source data as follows:
[image]

**How to display it with new line of "hello world"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Templetor - The web.py templating system (web.py)](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor):

> ### Filtering
>
> By default, Templetor uses web.websafe filter to do HTML-encoding.
>
> ```
> >>> render.hello("1 < 2")
> "Hello 1 &lt; 2"
> ```
>
> To turnoff filter **use : after $**. For example:
>
> ```
> The following will not be html escaped.
> $:form.render()
> ```

So, replace `$item`... with `$:item`... .